# Uploading Cookbook to the Chef Supermarket is failing with Authentication Error

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to upload the Cookbook to the Chef Supermarket and it is failing with the below error

```
# knife supermarket share starter -VV
INFO: Using configuration from /root/chef-repo/.chef/config.rb
INFO: Validating ruby files
INFO: Validating templates
INFO: Syntax OK
Generating metadata for starter from /tmp/chef-starter-build20231025-11775-6q4gys/starter/metadata.rb
Making tarball starter.tgz
DEBUG: Signing: method: post, url: https://supermarket.chef.io/api/v1/cookbooks, file: #<File:0x0000000002fa4b58>, User-id: vinothini02, Timestamp: 2023-10-25T13:13:39Z
ERROR: Authentication failed due to an invalid public/private key pair. If you have changed your keys recently try logging out and logging back in to Supermarket.
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an account in the chef infra (https://api.chef.io/)
and download the **client pem** moving to My account (https://id.chef.io/id/profile). Use this pem under the **.chef** directory.